# Reset Sequence Number With Change of Month

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

(Cell A1) Invoice Reference No. **EPS-I-S151001**

(Cell B1) Invoice Date                **05/Oct/15**

Once the Invoice Date is manually entered, Invoice Reference No will be automatically generated.

The format of Reference No is as follows: **EPS-I-S151001**.

**"EPS-I-S"** are fixed characters throughout.

First 2 digits, "15" = "Year"

Next 2 digits, "10" = "Month"

Last 2 digits, "01" = Running Numbers from 01 onwards.

For example:

**Invoice Ref No           Invoice Date**

EPS-I-S151001              10-Nov-15

EPS-I-S151002              15-Nov-15

EPS-I-S151003              30-Nov-15

The last 2 digits will continue to run in sequence.

1st 4 digits will be affected by any change in either Month or Year. Any change in either Month or Year, will prompt the last 2 numbers to be reset back to **01**.

**Invoice Ref No**      **Invoice Date**

EPS-I-S151001           10-Nov-15

EPS-I-S151002           15-Nov-15

EPS-I-S15**1201**       22-**Dec**-15 **(New Month)**

EPS-I-S151202           23-Dec-15

EPS-I-S151203           25-Dec-15

EPS-I-S16**0101**       03-**Jan**-**16** **(New Year/Month)**

EPS-I-S160102           15-Jan-16

EPS-I-S160103           22-Jan-16

Comment: Huh?  What’s in Column C?  What’s on Sheet2?  Why is the formula for cell `A1` using data from row 3 and Sheet2 row 4?  How does 2015/Oct/01 “point to” a range of numbers (and, since it’s October, why isn’t it 1-31)?  Please clarify what data you have and what you want Excel to do for you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had updated the details. Once the user enters the Invoice Date, Cell B3 will automatically reflect as EPS-I-S151001. On the next new line entry, it will show as EPS-I-S151002 and having the last 2 numbers to run in sequence. Until the user enters a new month or new year, e.g. 05/Nov/15 or 05/Jan/16, the last 2 numbers will auto reset and start from 01 again, e.g. EPS-I-S151101 or EPS-I-S160101. Are we able to do this?

Comment: I’m still having a lot of trouble understanding this.  I guess you’re saying that the user types data into cells `A3` and `C3`, and you want Excel to display `B3` automatically — so the formula that you give in your question is for cell `B3` (rather than `A1`, which is what you said).  And you want to ignore the fact that `C3` is ***the 5th of*** October, and just start `B3` at `xxxxxxxxxxx01`.  And if the user enters an invoice number in `A4` (?), but leaves `C4` blank, you want `B4` to be `xxxxxxxxxxx02` (`B3`+1)(?)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So, if `A3:A13` have numbers in them, and `C4:C13` are blank, then `B13` should be set to `EPS-I-S151011`.  And if the user enters 05/Mar/16 in `C14`, you want `B14` to be `EPS-I-S160301`.  Am I close?

Comment: Try to add picture to highlight, not enough reputation to do so. Hence I updated my question again, hope it is more clear now. Your last part comment is correct. Only Date (Col C) and Serial No (Col A) will be entered by user. And the date input will determines the Reference No.

Comment: What is your problem? It's not clear from the post. Do you want to complete the formula to add serial no (replace `???` to `TEXT(A3,"00")`)? Or do you have problem with calculation of serial no as suggested by title (in A3: `=IF(MONTH(C3)=MONTH(C2),A2+1,1)`)?

Comment: I have a clue to what you're looking for from your other question.  If you are manually entering A3, your problem is trivial; just concatenate A3 for the last two digits.  I suspect A3 is left over from trying to develop this from a manual process.  Your description sounds like you want to calculate the last two digits.  You could do it in A3 as a helper column and concatenate that in your B3 formula, or just include it in the formula.  You describe year or month changing, but you can probably simplify that to just looking at the month.  (cont'd)

Comment: That will work as long as it isn't a full year between invoices.  Máté Juhász's comment, above, includes the kind of formula you would use in A3 and then concatenate A3 in B3.  Or leave off the equal sign and include it in your B3 formula to calculate the last two digits (embed it in TEXT(formula,"00") to keep it two digits with a leading zero if needed).  If you want B3 hidden until a date is entered, embed your entire formula in IF(ISBLANK(C3),"",formula).

Comment: @MátéJuhász please ignored Cell A3 Serial No, as it is just for records count. The main focus will be on cell B3 Invoice Reference No. You are right I need your kind expertise to help me complete the formula, I only managed to settle the formulas for the 1st 4 numbers.

Comment: @Brandon:  The discussion has gotten kind of long and confusing.  It isn't clear at this point what portion of the problem is still unsolved and what the shortcomings are of the current suggestions.  It would help if you could clean up the question by consolidating the relevant comments back into it.   Maybe update your formulas to the extent you have been able to incorporate the suggestions, and describe how they don't work relative to your objective.  That will provide a clearer picture for people to take a fresh look.

Comment: My sincere apologies to you kind guys out there, trying to help me solve my issue. Sorry for the trouble. I had updated my question once again, hope this is better than the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, but please don't make bigger changes than you need to.  You've got a day's worth of comments referring to Column B as Invoice Reference Number and Column C as Invoice Date, and now you've gone and invalidated all of them.  You should have just said "Disregard Column A" rather than deleting it and shifting everything over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we've got a solution for you:

[image]

Ignore the slightly different date format, it's just formatting.  I needed to leave a blank first data line because the date gets compared to the previous line and that needed to be either blank or a date in LibraOffice Calc (skipping it might work in Excel, didn't have ready access to test that).  An alternative would be to hard code the first Invoice number in row 2.

So starting the formula in A3 would be:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"","EPS-I-S"&TEXT(B3,"yy")&TEXT(B3,"mm")&TEXT(IF(MONTH(B3)=MONTH(B2),VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))+1,1),"00"))
```

Copy that down column A as far as you need.  The cells will remain blank until you enter a date in column B.  That's what the ISBLANK test does at the beginning.  You had already figured out the next several terms, although you removed it when you updated the question.  They provide the prefix, year and month.

That brings us to the sequence number.  A change in year also involves a change in month (assuming you don't go an entire year until the next invoice, in which case you would have bigger things to worry about than this spreadsheet).  So if the date is in the same month as the previous date, it adds `1` to the number.  Otherwise it starts with `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, this is exactly what I need. You are quite spot on..i did tried to skip a year ahead and the count went wrong. But you are right, we shall be more worried about the state of the business rather than the spreadsheet.....lol..... Other than fixer1234, i would also like to express my thanks to Scott and Mate for your kind time and trying to understand my problem...sorry for the confusion and any headache caused earlier....lol

Comment: @Brandon: The official way to show thanks is to [“accept” an answer](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to it.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @Fixer1234, I am currently using your formula above, =IF(ISBLANK(B3),"","EPS-I-S"&TEXT(B3,"yy")&TEXT(B3,"mm")&TEXT(IF(MONTH(B3)=MONTH(B2),VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))+1,1),"00")) to show EPS-Q-AW151001. Right now I would need to make some changes to show new format, EPS-P-151001/C1003. I tried to used this formula =IF(ISBLANK(C6),"","EPS-P-"&TEXT(C6,"yy")&TEXT(C6,"mm")&TEXT(IF(MONTH(C6)=MONTH(C5),VALUE(RIGHT(B5,2))+1,1),"00")&"/"&VLOOKUP(E6,DB!$K$3:$L$16,2,FALSE)) but the counter do not reflect the squence number in it. By right it shall show EPS-P-151002/C1003, but instead it show as EPS-P-151010/C1003

Comment: @Brandon: I'm not following where EPS-Q-AW comes from (unimportant?). There isn't enough info here to understand what you're doing with the /C1003, but it sounds like the only issue is in the "old" portion of the S/N. I can guess at the cause. RIGHT(B5,2), which is the portion involved with those two digits, looks at the right 2 char's of the previous S/N (which is where they used to be). Now the right 2 char's are part of the new /C1003.  The 2 digits you want are now in the middle.  Replace RIGHT(B5,2) with MID(B5,11,2).  Verify that.  It starts with the 11th char and includes 2 char's.

Comment: @Fixer1234, Thank you so much for your kind advise. You are spot on. I did tried MID() just now but end up with error, maybe I get the Char part wrong. Once again thanks for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are much easier to solve if you use “helper columns” —
columns that hold intermediate results that you don’t want to display,
but that go into constructing the value that you do want. 
For this problem, I’ll use one helper column,
and its contents will be obvious once you see them. 
I’ll use Column `G`. 
Referring to a previous version of your question,
I’ll assume that your data start in row 3,
and I’ll assume that cell `G2` is blank.

- Set `G3` to `=IF(TEXT(B3,"yymm")<>TEXT(B2,"yymm"), 1, G2+1)`
  This says “If the invoice date on this line (`B3`)
  has a different year or month from the date on the previous line (`B2`),
  then set `G3` to `1`; otherwise, add `1` to the previous value (`G2`).” 
  I.e., this is a running series that resets to `1` whenever there is a new month.
- Set `A3` to `=IF(B3="", "", "EPS-I-S" & TEXT(B3, "yymm") & TEXT(G3, "00"))`
  This says “If the invoice date on this row (cell `B3`) is blank,
  display nothing. 
  Otherwise, build the invoice reference number using the constant string,
  the year and the month from the date in Column `B`,
  and the one-up number from Column `G`
  (formatted as a two-digit number, with a leading zero if necessary).”

Then drag/fill the formulas in Columns `A` and `G` down
as far as you want.

[image]

Note: once you have everything working, you can hide the helper columns.

Comment: @ Scott, Thanks. I had tried your solution but the counter at B3 is not displaying correctly. I had setup my requirements exactly to your screenshot. When I enter 2 on Cell A4 Serial No, it show EPS-I-151002. This is what I need. But the moment I entered the date next to it, it jump back to EPS-I-151001, which is incorrect. Cell G4 also face the same problem.

Comment: Any chance, not to link Column B to Column A, as it is not related.  Can we just tied to only Column C instead?

Comment: The automated running sequence number is actually the last 2 numbers of Invoice Reference No, not for the Serial Number. Sorry for your confusion and trouble caused

Comment: I’ve told you repeatedly that I’m having trouble understanding your statement of your problem — and, looking at the comments on the question, I’m not the only one.  So, please, don’t leave out details.       You say, “But the moment I entered the date next to it, it jump back to EPS-I-151001, which is incorrect.”  Please be explicit.  Are you saying that you entered “5-Oct-15” into `C4`?  And are you saying, if you enter “5-Oct-15” into cells `C4:C13`, you want `B4:B13` to be `EPS-I-S151002`-`EPS-I-S151011`?  Or can it be “6-Oct-15”, “7-Oct-15”, “9-Oct-15”, “12-Oct-15”, “17-Oct-15”, …?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the formula, it worked wonderful till Serial # 100. After 100 it restarted from 001
Here is my formula: =IF(ISBLANK(N6),"",F6&"-"&TEXT(O6,"yyyy")&"-"&TEXT(IF(YEAR(N6)=YEAR(N5),VALUE(RIGHT(A5,2))+1,1),"000"))
Its output is OHSAS-2020-001 / EMS-2019-001 etc where OHSAS / EMS is Standard, 2020/2019 is the year and 001 is the NUMBER

Comment: It restart after 100 because the question explicitly asked for that behaviour.